# what is the formal statement terminator with db2 sql

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I have added `/` character as statement terminator all in my db2 statements. I can run sql file in data studio client without any issue. But when I run the sql file in db2 command prompt by issuing `db2 -tsvf db2.sql` command I got

```
DB21007E End of file reached while reading the command.
```

error. I could resolve this issue by changing statement terminator character from `/` to `;`. 
My question is should I keep statement terminator character as `/` or `;`? If I keep `/`, is there any way to run sql file from command line also?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need to use the `-td<statement terminator>` syntax. So you would need to format the above as follows:

```
db2 -td/ -svf db2.sql
```

This would tell DB2 that your statement terminator is the `/` character, otherwise, yes the default is the semicolon `;`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the terminator in the file itself, by adding this comment as the first line like a shebang

```
--#SET TERMINATOR /
```

Comment: Technically speaking, it doesn't need to be the _first_ line, as long as it comes before the statements that use that character as a terminator.